# Keyboard shortcut to Toggle (hide/show) my chrome extension

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension, browser-action

I am working on extension, i want my chrome extension to toggle (show / hide) via command like say (mac: "CMD+SHIFT+9" or default: "Ctrl+Shift+9");
Though i have defined command in my manifest file:

```
{
  ......... 
  "commands": {
    "toggle-window": {
      "suggested_key": {
        "default": "Ctrl+Shift+9",
        "mac": "Command+Shift+9"
      },
      "description": "Toggle feature foo",
      "global": true
    },
    ........
 }
```

Now, What can i do in my backgroundScript.js to do that?

my backgroundScript.js is:

```
chrome.commands.onCommand.addListener(function(command) {
  if(command === "toggle-window") {
      console.log('Command:', command);
      /* Logic to show/hide will go here..*/
  }
});
```

How do i do do that? Thanks!

Sample Extension demo that have this "show/hide" feature implemented:

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/meldium-browser-extension/fdocegmnehjgfhfjelhmaobjccoiklle

Comment: When I first saw this in the triage review queue, i thought this looked like an decent question...but as I read i saw this phrase:  "Give me a code plz...".  Don't do that.  We're not here to write your code for you, but we're happy to help answer any specific questions you have.

Comment: I'm guessing what you want by the behaviour of that extension...you don't need any logic in your background script for that. Just use "_execute_browser_action" instead of "toggle-window" in your manifest file, chrome will handle this functionality for you. Read [this](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/commands).

Comment: Thanks for the response though, I didn't want you to give me axact code what i mean was just give me basic idea, Though i am trying what you have described, and will let you know about it.. Thanks

Comment: I tried this "_execute_browser_action" in my manifest file. It's not working at my side.

Comment: Also I am testing it locally in the Dev Mode!

Comment: @CViejo I got it solved! You were right that using "_execute_browser_action", chrome will handle this functionality for us, nicely... Thanks buddy!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long research i finally got it solved.. First of all, thanks to @CViejo, He gave me a hint to the problem:

> "Just use "_execute_browser_action" instead of "toggle-window" in your manifest file, chrome will handle this functionality for you.

I updated my manifest.js file like this as @CViejo said:

```
{
  ......... 
  "commands": {
    "_execute_browser_action": {
      "suggested_key": {
        "default": "Ctrl+Shift+9",
        "mac": "Command+Shift+9"
      }
    }
    ........
 }
```

then, i reloaded my extension but it still didn't worked.. then i just find **keyboard shortcuts** box on the bottom of the extensions page, i read about it online, it basically helps us "to verify that suggested keys are actually set there on Keyboard shortcuts box that are defined in manifest file". i checked the **keyboard shortcuts** box the key was not set, even if the key was available and defined in the manifest.

And then from the stack overflow, i found this one (that was major mistake): https://stackoverflow.com/a/25654514/5228251

> As you can see in the source code here:
>   https://code.google.com/p/chromium/codesearch#chromium/src/chrome/browser/extensions/api/commands/command_service.cc&l=303&sq=package:chromium&rcl=1409677023
>
> The key binding update is only run when OnExtensionWillBeInstalled
>   callback is triggered.
>
> So you need to uninstall and reinstall your local extension to see the
>   default keyboard command appear in :
>   chrome://extensions/configureCommands

I just did uninstalled an re-installed my unpacked extension and checked that default keyboard command appear in chrome://extensions/configureCommands

And it started worked in my extension...

Many Thanks to @CViejo and @Stephane Brillant...

May this also help others.....

Comment: I’m trying that last uninstall/reinstall with an unpacked extension right now and getting nothing. I wonder if this has changed (or if I’m missing something else)?

Comment: *UPDATE:* looks like I was potentially falling into this issue (tried Ctrl+Shift+P)—“*Certain Chrome shortcuts (e.g. window management) always take priority over Extension Command shortcuts and can not be overwritten.” https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/commands — it works when I use a different key.

Comment: @MrColes Yes, you're absolutely right. "Your custom shortcut needs to be the different one from the chrome's default (pre-defined) ones" ! :thumbsup