# Create a keyboard shortcut to launch a Google Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

Is it possibble to create a keyboard shortcut inside a Google Chrome extension?  My Google search so far has not helped answer this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chrome: Chrome has all kinds of [great keyboard shortcuts](http://lifehacker.com/5045904/the-power-users-guide-to-google-chrome) to make browsing quick and easy, but they're not really customizable. Digital Inspiration reminds us that you can also set custom keyboard shortcuts for certain extensions.

Just head to `chrome://extensions/` in your browser's address bar to open up the extensions page. Scroll down to the bottom and you'll see a Keyboard Shortcuts option. Click it, and you can set up custom shortcuts for some of you extensions.

Comment: Thanks for the answer however I was referring to adding keyboard shortcut using code in my chrome extension released to the public similar to how you can add your own right click context menus in an extension.  It seems it might not be possibble though

Comment: do you mean this ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18132873/chrome-commands-keyboard-shortcuts-not-working-for-me

Answer (score 0):

The other answer is generally true, but note that one can't ***unset*** a shortcut if the extension sets a default. This is likely an [issue with Chromium](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1275357).